# Tracing errors caused by hitting max number of sockets to single host?

Tags: linux-networking

For the TCP protocol, there's a maximum number of 65536 connections from one host to another host running a server on a particular port. What is the error code returned by the kernel when a connection fails when there are no available source ports and is there a simple `bpftrace` script that can be used to count failures caused by this?

Comment: Fairly good writeup here. Depending on the scenario, could be  EADDRNOTAVAIL or   EADDRINUSE or EAGAIN or EPERM. 
 https://blog.cloudflare.com/how-to-stop-running-out-of-ephemeral-ports-and-start-to-love-long-lived-connections